# React Hooks: Does defining a hook with a default value trigger a rerender due to it being a new object?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook `useHook` and it has an optional options param `options: {thing1: string}`. In this example, the object is assigned when there is not an `options` param passed.

My question is, when there is **not** an options parameter will the options object be effectively memoized during the re-render process? Or, will the hook view it as a new object with exactly the same data?

```
export const useHook = ({
    options = { thing1: 'test_name'}
}) => {
    // ... Does some logic
}
```

Finally, is a better pattern to require a `options` param and have one defined?

```
export const DEFAULT_USEHOOK_OPTIONS = { thing1: 'test_name'}
```

Comment: No, they will not be memoized